# Aviary "forceCropPreset" not working

Tags: javascript, aviary

I have the underneath code, the editor loads and does not give errors.
It does however not enforce the cropping/resizing of the image.
I copied the config straight out of the examples,.. (except for the theme that is)
But it somehow does not work.

Can anyone help out?

```
aviaryObject = new Aviary.Feather({
    apiKey: 'xxxx',
    apiVersion: 3,
    tools: 'all',
    theme: 'light',
    onSave: function(imageID, newURL) {
        var img = document.getElementById(imageID);
        img.src = newURL;
    },
    onError: function(errorObj) {
        alert(errorObj.message);
    }
});

aviaryObject.launch({
    image: 'imgId',
    url: [server-url],
    forceCropPreset: ['Logo','150x150'],
    forceCropMessage: 'Please crop your photo to this size',
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution, as I'm using https I had to load a different script file.
So if you want to use aviary over a https connection, use:

```
https://dme0ih8comzn4.cloudfront.net/js/feather.js
```